# How does this code work? (Java)

Tags: java, random, int

I have program in which 4 random numbers are set to 4 buttons (one no. for each button). There are two random variables (rbvalue and loadG4). The rbvalue number is different for each button, but the loadG4 value overrides a button's value and replaces it. The idea is, none of the rbvalue numbers are meant to be equal to loadG4, and a part of the program ensures they are never equal. Here's the code:

```
Random GenerateG4 = new Random();
            int loadG4 = GenerateG4.nextInt(10);
            Random randoms1 = new Random();
            final TextView number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
            number.setText(""+loadG4);
            for(int allrbA=0; allrbA<4; allrbA++) {
                int rbvalue = randoms1.nextInt(10 - 1);
                if (rbvalue==loadG4) rbvalue=9;
                selectrb[allrbA].setText(""+rbvalue);
            }
            selectrb[rbselector].setText(""+loadG4);
```

The part that makes this work is:

```
if (rbvalue==loadG4) rbvalue=9;
```

Simply adding that line of code in did the job. Now out of all numbers generated from 0 to 9, there is only one of which is the value of loadG4. How did that one line do this? I always thought that after `if (...)` there has to be curly brackets for the actual statements e.g if (...) {System.out.println("...")}  Why set rbvalue to 9? Why is there (10 -1) for the random rbvalue? What does that -1 even mean in this situation?

I'd appreciate anyone who could clear this up for me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can take `10 - 1` as primary school math, it equals 9, so `randoms1.nextInt(10 - 1)` returns a number from 0 through 8 inclusive. I don’t know why it’s not written as `9`. It might be an attempt to stress that the value is 1 smaller than the 10 used in `GenerateG4.nextInt(10)`.

When only one statement is executed when the `if` condition is true, the curly braces are a matter of opinion. Very many prefer to have them there; in my workplace no one gets away with leaving them out.

The `if` statement sets `rbvalue` to 9 if it was equal to `loadG4`. That will make sure the values differ. Since `rbvalue` was at most 8, we know that when they are equal, setting one of them to 9 will ensure they become different. It’s a bit subtle for my taste, I understand you needed to ask.

The code doesn’t appear to do anything to make the `rbvalue` numbers different for each button.